# CheckBox dropdownlist with grouping in JSF

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, checkbox, dropdownchecklist

I need to have a checkbox dropdown list which is grouped and the group header should also be selectable. If u select the group header all the children under the group should be selected. I tried using the jquery ui dropdownchecklist with grouping but the group header was non selectable for it. Check out the image link below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbD7L.jpg]

As u see, 'Timesheet' is non selectable. I need 'Timesheet' and 'Supplementary timesheet' to have a checkbox and if u click on it, all its children must be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using DDCL,
First you need to download an updated ***ui.dropdownchecklist.js*** from [here (ui.dropdownchecklist with patch)](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/issues/attachmentText?id=24&aid=240012000&name=ui.dropdownchecklist.js&token=ABZ6GAeizXCMyyaVDtvIHJx52lI2amHNMA%3A1409137694839). It has been patched with an additional *groupItemChecksWholeGroup* Tag.

All you need to do is set the groupItemChecksWholeGroup : true.

See the code below

Code for ManagedBean

```
public ArrayList<SelectItem> cars;
SelectItemGroup g1=new SelectItemGroup("BMWs");
SelectItemGroup g2=new SelectItemGroup("Audi");
g1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{new SelectItem("320D", "320D"),new SelectItem("520D","520D"),new SelectItem("620D","620D"),new SelectItem("720D","720D")});
g2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]{new SelectItem("A3","A3"),new SelectItem("A6","A6"),new SelectItem("Q3","Q3"),new SelectItem("Q5","Q5"),new SelectItem("Q7","Q7")});
cars = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
cars.add(g1);
cars.add(g2);
```

Below is the code for the Html file

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="s1" value="">
<f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="All" itemValue="1" />
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.cars}" />
```

Then add this jQuery script in your Html head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#s1").dropdownchecklist({
        firstItemChecksAll : true,
        groupItemChecksWholeGroup : true,
        width : 250
    });
});
```

The result will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about using PrimeFaces tree with checkbox? Take a look at their showcase example

[Tree - Selection - Checkbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/selection.xhtml)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel. It surely matches my requirement, just that can i have the tree non-collapsable?